# change in Rayleigh quotient for a small perturbation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

for a real non symmetric matrix for a small perturbation $\delta v$ find change in Rayleigh quotient $\delta r = r(v+\delta v) - r(v)$ to first order in $\delta v$.

i know that for real and symmetric matrices Rayleigh quotient is defined as $r(x,A) = x^TAx/x^Tx$ and from here on we can differentiate $r(x)$ and solve the problem but i am unable to solve this for non symmetric matrices any kind of hints would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can expand the numerator and denominator as follows:
$$
\begin{align}
(v + \delta v)^TA(v + \delta v) &= 
v^TAv + \delta v^TAv + v^TA\delta v + \delta v^TA\delta v
\\ & = 
v^TAv + v^TA^T\delta v + v^TA\delta v + \delta v^TA\delta v
\\ & = v^TAv + v^T(A + A^T)\delta v + o(\delta v),\\
(v + \delta v)^T(v + \delta v) &= v^Tv + 2 v^T\delta v + o(\delta v).
\end{align}
$$
From there, we have
$$
\begin{align}
R(v + \delta v,A) &= [v^TAv + v^T(A + A^T)\delta v + o(\delta v)] \cdot [v^Tv + 2 v^T\delta v + o(\delta v)]^{-1}
\\ & = [v^TAv + v^T(A + A^T)\delta v + o(\delta v)] \cdot 
[(v^Tv)^{-1} - (v^Tv)^{-2}\cdot 2v^T\delta v + o(\delta v)]
\\ & = \frac{v^TAv}{v^Tv} + \left[\frac{v^T(A + A^T)}{v^Tv} - 2\frac{v^TAvv^T}{(v^Tv)^2}\right]\delta v + o(\delta v).
\end{align}
$$